# How to use swiper 10 with angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I am migrating to **Swiper 10** and hence updated the code as per the guidelines provided by [swiperjs.com](https://swiperjs.com/get-started). But strangely not able to make a simple Swiper work!! On clicking the left / right arrow, the screen is not swiping out!! After many efforts, still completely stuck.
Added the stackblitz link with the code. Need your help please to point out where am I going wrong. Thanks.

**[Link to stackblitz…]**(https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-y5jczf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

here is the code snip…

- **app.component.html**

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-content>
    <div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-app>
```

- **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import Swiper from 'swiper';
import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper/modules';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  public swiper = new Swiper('.mySwiper', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,

    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },

    // And if we need scrollbar
    scrollbar: {
      el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    },
    modules: [Navigation, Pagination],
  });

  constructor() {}

  ionViewDidEnter() {}
}
```

- **app.component.css**

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

- **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import Swiper from 'swiper';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, IonicModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [Swiper],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

- **styles.css**

```
@import 'swiper/css';
@import 'swiper/css/navigation';
@import 'swiper/css/pagination';
```

- **Code output**
  [screen snip...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RsYI.png)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01jwVb3WLoA

Comment: Thank Najam. But this video is for Swiper 9. The above issue is with Swiper 10 (v10.2.0). Any working example of Swiper 10 with Angular or Ionic would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: do same as described in Video and it will work. I am using v10 in my application with same video configuration and it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Najam. Swiper v9 syntax is working fine with Swiper v10 (v10.2.0). Hence, as a workaround, have replaced the v10 code with the v9 code. 

However, as Swiper v10 syntax is quite elegant and generic (primarily using DIV only), it will be great to have working Swiper code with v10 syntax.